# Hide Toolbar when adding XsltListViewWebPart programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, xlv

I'm currently using Sharepoint 2016. I added a document library XsltListViewWebPart into my page using C#. I am trying to remove the toolbar.
First i did this:

```
myWebPat.Toolbar = "None";
```

Nothing happen. Then i tried the following:

```
//Set toolbar type to None
MethodInfo ensureViewMethod = lvwp.GetType().GetMethod("EnsureView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
object[] ensureViewParams = { };
ensureViewMethod.Invoke(lvwp, ensureViewParams);
FieldInfo viewFieldInfo = lvwp.GetType().GetField("view", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
SPView spView = viewFieldInfo.GetValue(lvwp) as SPView;
Type[] toolbarMethodParamTypes = { Type.GetType("System.String") };
MethodInfo setToolbarTypeMethod = spView.GetType().GetMethod("SetToolbarType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, toolbarMethodParamTypes, null);
object[] setToolbarParam = { "None" };
setToolbarTypeMethod.Invoke(spView, setToolbarParam);
```

But i hit error at:

```
FieldInfo viewFieldInfo = lvwp.GetType().GetField("view", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
SPView spView = viewFieldInfo.GetValue(lvwp) as SPView;
```

The error message is:

> The object is not set to an instance of an Object.

Apparently, the viewFieldInfo gives me null value.

Is there any other approach?